# Update indexedDb within Ajax returns error: The transaction has finished?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, indexeddb

**I'm tryin to update mysql with data from IndexedDb.**

I loop threw the IndexedDb and inset data to mysql.
When a ajax call is complete the loop should contineu.

But i get this error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'update' on 'IDBCursor': The transaction has finished.

I can se that the Ajax call returned success and mySql is updated.
But when it comes to update the IndexDb it returns error.

**This is the code:**

```
//UPDATE/SYNC INDEXEDDB WITH MYSQL
function update_mysql(){
    
    //UPDATE INFO TEXT
    $('#info_text').text('Öppnar IndexedDb..');
 
    //OPEN CONNECTION TO INDEXEDDB
    var transaction = db.transaction(["Orderlist"], "readwrite");
    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore('Orderlist');

    //FETCH DATA FROM INDEXEDDB
    objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) { 
        var cursor = event.target.result; 
        if (cursor) {
            
            //UPDATE INFO TEXT
            $('#info_text').text('Loopar igenom IndexedDb..');
            
            //IF STATUS = 1, SYNC/UPDATE
            if (cursor.value.status == "1") { 
                
                var order_id = cursor.value.id;
                var sum_received = cursor.value.sum_received;
                
                //UPDATE INFO TEXT
                $('#info_text').text('Ansluter till databasen..');

                //SEND DATA TO PHP
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'php/update_mysql_orderlist.php',
                    method: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {order_id: order_id, sum_received: sum_received},
                    success: function(result){
                        //UPDATE INFO TEXT
                        $('#info_text').text('Order med id: '+order_id+' updaterad i mySql');
                    },
                    complete: function(){
                        //UPDATE INDEXDB STATUS
                        var updateData = cursor.value;
                        updateData.status = "2";
                        var request = cursor.update(updateData);
                        
                        //REQUST SUCCESS
                        request.onsuccess = function() {
                            console.log('Order with id: '+order_id+' is now updated with IndexedDb!');
                        };
                        
                        //CONTINUE LOOP
                        cursor.continue();
                    }
                });
            }
            //IF STATUS != 1
            else{
                //CONTINUE LOOP
                cursor.continue();
            }
        }
        else {
            //LOOP IS DONE!
            console.log('Update/sync completed!');
        }
    };
};
```

**Better solution?**
Should i first get data from IndexedDb and save to array and then make only one transaction with Ajax? and then update IndexedDb?! Is that a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the ajax call before starting a transaction. You cannot mix async calls with ajax together with indexedDB transactions. IndexedDB transactions will automatically close very shortly after it detects there are no active requests in the transaction.

Comment: My solution was to get indexedDb and put it in a json. Then send it with ajax.